# Is for loop for bash file traversal deterministic?

Tags: bash, file

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=/path/to/*
for f in $FILES
do
  echo "Processing $f file..."
done
```

Is the above code guaranteed to traverse the folder in a deterministic way? That is, is it possible that multiple executions for loop with the exact same folder(and the files in it) produce different results?

Comment: Globs are sorted, as long as your locale _has_ a sort order (and is held constant).

Comment: BTW, that has nothing to do with `for` specifically -- `/path/to/*` behaves the same way in any context where glob expansion takes place.

Comment: Thanks, that resolves my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is. According to the [Bash Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html#Filename-Expansion)

> After word splitting, unless the `-f` option has been set (see The Set Builtin), Bash scans each word for the characters `*`, `?`, and `[`. If one of these characters appears, then the word is regarded as a *pattern*, and replaced with an alphabetically sorted list of filenames matching the pattern (see Pattern Matching).

It doesn't say so explicitly in the above section, but I presume that "alphabetically" is sensitive to locale settings. So it may not produce the same sequence of you change any of the `LC_*` environment variables.